# In which branch should a beta release be tagged?

Tags: git, release, release-management, git-flow

In which branch should a beta release be tagged according to git-flow?

We have a release branch for preparing Version `x.0.0`, but before releasing `x.0.0` we want to release a beta (`x.0.0-beta`). Should the release branch be merged into `master` in this case and then be tagged `x.0.0-beta` on `master` or should this beta release be tagged on the release branch for `x.0.0`?

Additional question: Is the procedure for a release candidate (`x.0.0-rc1`) the same as for beta?

Comment: Given that a) you want good master at all times and b) it doesn't make any difference whatsoever (from git perspective), I'd say tag the release branch.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

I would suggest that you would place the `x.0.0-beta` tag on the release branch, once you are ready to ship the beta version, somewhere.  You might actually want to go further and tag it with `x.0.0-beta0001` so that you can have multiple beta version, as required.

Once you move closer to the release, you would tag the release branch with the `x.0.0-rc1` as required as well.

Then, once you merge the release branch into master, and ultimately back into develop, you would tag the master branch with the final version number.

This approach was taken from the implementation of git-flow in the GitVersion utility, which is documented here:

https://gitversion.net/docs/learn/branching-strategies/gitflow/examples

Answer (score 6):

In my understanding all versions should be merged to and tagged on the master branch. As all Release branches should follow this flow.
Semantic versioning should prevent people from updating to the released alpha/beta/RC versions.

This keeps your flow clean and straight forward. I.E. No branches are left open to clean up at a later date. And you always finish release branches in the same way after you've upped version number and tested your code.

### Optional

You could remove all preliminary tags for a specific version after the real release. Yet again this is to keep your flow clean. As people are probably not going to checkout 'unstable' versions of a full and stable release.

```
1.2.0-alpha
1.1.0
1.1.0-rc2
1.1.0-rc1
1.0.0
1.0.0-beta1
1.0.0-alpha1
```

Would become

```
1.2.0-alpha
1.1.0
1.0.0
```

Comment: How can you tag the master branch, with commits that haven't been merged into the master branch yet?

Comment: I implied merging to master, let me add it the answer explicitly.

Comment: Master is in most cases considered a stable branch. Merging in betas and pre-releases would make it an unstable branch.

Comment: @ikke: That seems to be the root of this issue. In my proposal we would define stable as code which has been tested and contains runtime errors at most. As opposed to the `develop` branch where a new feature may not work as intended or might not work alongside another new feature. Like I stated in the answer, the semantic versioning would keep this system together. NPM, Bower, Composer would not break your system depending on using this flow.